# Flutter use delay in provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form that displays a popup with a message inside.
While the popup is displayed I perform calculations and depending on the state of the calculations I change the message in the popup.

My system works but if I want to apply a delay before the change of message, the change of message in the popup is no longer carried out ... why?

Call to my screen :

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider<FormCalculatorNotifier>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => FormCalculatorNotifier()
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<LoaderNotifier>(
        create: (BuildContext context) => LoaderNotifier()
    ),
  ],
  child: CalculatorScreen(),
);
```

The button in ma screen that call the popup

```
Expanded(
  child:  ButtonComponent.primary(
    context: context,
    text: AppTextButton.CALCUL,
    onPressed: () async {
      await _formProvider.submitForm(context);
      if(_formProvider.state == FormProviderState.isSuccess){

          // Here I load my popup
          final _loaderProvider = Provider.of<LoaderNotifier>(context, listen: false);
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return DialogComponent.loadingPopUp(description: _loaderProvider.message);
            },
          );

        //------------------------------------------
        // Here I simulate calculations and change state and message for the popup
        //------------------------------------------
        _loaderProvider.state = LoaderState.isLoadingJsons;
        await _loaderProvider.updateMessage();
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

The popup notifier :

```
class LoaderNotifier with ChangeNotifier {

  LoaderState state = LoaderState.isReady;
  TimerService timerService = locator<TimerService>();
  String message = "Start...";

  LoaderNotifier();

  Future<void> updateMessage() async{
    
    //------------------------------------------
    // Here I want a delay
    // If I remove this my system works
    await timerService.wait(2);
    //------------------------------------------

    print('update message');
    if(state == LoaderState.isLoadingJsons){
      message = "Loading files...";
    }

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is my wait service :

```
class TimerService{

  Future<void> wait(int seconds) async {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: seconds), () => {});
  }

}
```